# Running `ncdu .` yields: "Error: could not open /var/lib/snapd/void". Why?

Tags: permissions, snap, ncdu

Running:

```
sudo snap remove ncdu
sudo snap install ncdu
sudo chmod -R 777 *
sudo ncdu .
```

gives the error

```
  lqqqError!qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqk
  x                                                                   x
  x Error: could not open /var/lib/snapd/void                         x
  x   Error reading directory: Permission denied                      x
  x                                                                   x
  x                                      press any key to continue... x
  mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj
```

What could the issue be?

---

`sudo ls -la /var/lib/snapd/void` returns:

```
total 8
d--x--x--x  2 root root 4096 Mar 26  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Apr 21 07:35 ..
```

I use Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa). The current folder `.` is `/hdd/workspace_dernonco0/audio/`.

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 *` is in almost *any case* not the right step. The question also does not include on what directory you ran this (or what `.` refers to). I hope it's not `/`?

Comment: Why use `snap` (and why the `remove`) if `ncdu` is available in the Ubuntu repos?

Comment: Searching for this on the internet shows that this appears to be a [common](https://forum.rclone.org/t/permission-denied-on-var-lib-snapd-void-copying-from-google-drive/2424) [problem](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/3143) with `snap` applications. Have you tried the version in your package manager instead?

Comment: @PankiThanks, the current folder `.` is `/hdd/workspace_dernonco0/audio/`.  I'll let you know once how I find out how to use the non-snap version. I use `remove` to reinstall it. No particular reason to use `ncdu` AFAIR.

Comment: `sudo apt install ncdu` to install. Aside from the `chmod` being dead wrong in the first place, you're not running it on `/var/lib/snapd/` anyways so I don't see the point.

Comment: @Panki thanks, running `sudo apt install ncdu; ncdu` has the same error message.